# Refresh one chart according to the action in another chart in d3.js V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two d3 charts in separate divs on a single page. After clicking on bar, the line chart should update accordingly for e.g. the click action on specific bar, should add an appropriate line to a line chart in another div. I am able to create a click action on bar. How can I use this action from bar chart to update a line chart accordingly. Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VSi2obfAHEqA7gIrWPad) code.

```
bar_svg.selectAll("#bar_chart")
.data(TOP_TEN_CHANNELS)
.enter().append("rect")
.on("click", function (d){
console.log("inside_bar_fucntion "+ d.channel);
})
```

Comment: I use [PubSub](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) for things like this. The click events fires a custom event that the listener will then call the update function on the other chart.